# Problem with Stripes' submit

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0, stripes

I'm currently experiencing a problem with `submit` button in Stripes. It completely ignores event, that it should call. Actionbean is working on links with no problems... Im stuck on that for like 3 hours.

event in actionbean

```
@HandlesEvent("addc")
public Resolution addc() {
    log.debug("addc() contract={}", contract);
    contractFacade.create(contract);
    return new RedirectResolution(this.getClass(), "all");
}
```

jsp:

```
<s:form beanclass="actionbean.ContractsActionBean">
    <%@include file="forms/formContractDetails.jsp"%>

    <ul>
    <li><s:submit name="addc" class="submit" title="">Add C</s:submit></li>
    <li><s:link href="/all">Cancel</s:link></li>
    </ul>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Looks like the problem could be even in s:form tag. When I removed attr beanclass and added action="addc", it runs the event (tho it sends null data to it, currently trying to figure out how to send those right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Actionbean` was `@UrlBind`-ed on `{$event}`, changed it to `/ab/{$event}` and it works now. Probably some interference with index.jsp or something. This is the kind of stuff that will kill me some day. Whole day lost over 4 chars. Hope it will help someone else at least.